# You shouldn't log in to your accounts in a public network. But what if you are already signed in?

Tags: windows, internet

So if you are already signed in, does it send your account info again when connected to a new network? Or is it based on cookies only.

Answer (score 2):

Your premise is flawed.  Provided you are using your own hardware or hardware you trust, and the site uses HTTPS (which almost all sites do), if your computer does not throw up any cert warnings the site is arguably as safe to use as if it were on your home network.

You can't generalise as to safety of logging in, and cookies may not help you.  A securely designed site would invalidate authentication related cookies if your IP address changes.   (There is no single way to log in, but getting a cookie for a valid username & IP is quite common.)